# JavaScript Error = appendChild is not a function

Tags: javascript

Porque quando executo a função recebo o erro de: appendChild is not a function?

```js
function inserirNumeros(x) {

  let paragraph = document.createElement("p");
  let node = document.createTextNode("this is new");

  paragraph.appendChild(node);


  let display = document.getElementsByClassName("display");
  display.appendChild(paragraph)



}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1>Calculadora</h1>

  <div class="corpo">

    <div class="display">0</div>

    <div class="numeros">
      <div class="botoes" id="7" onclick="inserirNumeros(7)" value="7">7</div>
      <div class="botoes" id="8">8</div>
      <div class="botoes" id="9">9</div>
      <div class="operacoes" id="divisao">÷</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` retorna lista de itens, para usar appendChild em diferentes elementos é preciso iterar com um `for()` ou [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) ... cc @AugustoVasques estou fechando pois se trata de um erro de uso, é uma pergunta inclusive que já tem algumas outras que são exatamente o mesmo problema que cai inclusive nesse caso [Perguntas frequentes que já foram respondidas no SOpt](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8674/3635)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, entendi e concordo.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/495490/112052 | https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/492337/112052

Answer (score 2):

Quando executa a função `inserirNumeros()` recebe o erro...

> `appendChild is not a function?`

...porque na linha...

`let display = document.getElementsByClassName("display");`

...o método [`Document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) retorna um vetor do tipo [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) com todos os elementos que possuem o nome da classe `display`. No seu caso um vetor contendo apena um elemento.

Uma solução é em javascript fazer com que variável display referencie o primeiro elemento da `HTMLCollection` retornada por `Document.getElementsByClassName()`, lembrando que o índice inicial é o zero.

```js
function inserirNumeros(x) {

  let paragraph = document.createElement("p");
  let node = document.createTextNode("this is new");

  paragraph.appendChild(node);


  let display = document.getElementsByClassName("display")[0];
  display.appendChild(paragraph)
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1>Calculadora</h1>

  <div class="corpo">

    <div class="display">0</div>

    <div class="numeros">
      <div class="botoes" id="7" onclick="inserirNumeros(7)" value="7">7</div>
      <div class="botoes" id="8">8</div>
      <div class="botoes" id="9">9</div>
      <div class="operacoes" id="divisao">÷</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Outra solução seria atribuir ao elemento `<div class="display">0</div>` um [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/id), atributo identificador único global do elemento, e obter sua referência com [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

```js
function inserirNumeros(x) {

  let paragraph = document.createElement("p");
  let node = document.createTextNode("this is new");

  paragraph.appendChild(node);


  let display = document.getElementById("display");
  display.appendChild(paragraph)
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1>Calculadora</h1>

  <div class="corpo">

    <div id="display">0</div>

    <div class="numeros">
      <div class="botoes" id="7" onclick="inserirNumeros(7)" value="7">7</div>
      <div class="botoes" id="8">8</div>
      <div class="botoes" id="9">9</div>
      <div class="operacoes" id="divisao">÷</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Outra solução seria utilizar o método [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) que retorna o primeiro elemento dentro do documento que corresponde ao grupo especificado de seletores CSS.

```js
function inserirNumeros(x) {

  let paragraph = document.createElement("p");
  let node = document.createTextNode("this is new");

  paragraph.appendChild(node);


  let display = document.querySelector(".display");
  display.appendChild(paragraph)



}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1>Calculadora</h1>

  <div class="corpo">

    <div class="display">0</div>

    <div class="numeros">
      <div class="botoes" id="7" onclick="inserirNumeros(7)" value="7">7</div>
      <div class="botoes" id="8">8</div>
      <div class="botoes" id="9">9</div>
      <div class="operacoes" id="divisao">÷</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: o downvote não é meu, pra compensar o esforço +1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, fica tranquilo. Não imaginei nada. Obrigado.